# EMV Question : Cannot Read Tag 9F24, returned nothing

Tags: nfc, payment, emv

Per EMV standard, card tag 9F24 should be contain BIN and AFR , but i cannot read any data from the card . Is that my APDU comman is wrong ?  or 9F24 only occur in mobile device?

https://www.level2kernel.com/payment_account_reference.html

I try to read 9F24 from the card  it's response 6A 88 (Referenced data not found)

Reader APDU>> 9F24

Card Response << 64 88

```
byte[] byteArrayAPDU = new byte[]{(byte)0x80, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x24, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};
```

int nResult = SmartCardInterface.transmit(nCardHandle, byteArrayAPDU, byteArrayResponse);

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct requirement for cards to contain PAR. It is only an option (relatively new), so you may expect that existing cards might not be using it. 
PAR may also be returned in several ways and normally kernels are tested if they can handle PAR in templates 70 (retrieved with Read Record) and 77 (may be found in response to GPO, Internal Auth, GenAC, etc). You should probably refer to EMVCo description. You might want to use different data object (like BIN or card number and tokenize it yourself, depending what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: How about mobile payment ( Apple pay or Google pay ) , Do PAR is a  mandatory information for Apple pay and Google pay ?

Comment: Payment Networks Associations are putting plans in place to support PAR but they still rely on tokenization process because PAR is still not mandatory and enforced by EMV standards